# Jenkins using old node version to build project

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gulp, bower, nodemon

I am working on an existing job that builds a project using node but it looks like it will need to run on v8.11.1 specifically.

here are the following commands we use on Jenkins:

```
source ~/.profile
echo 'Install required packages'
npm install -g bower gulp nodemon
npm install
bower install


echo 'Building production code'
gulp build
```

It build our project successfully but only uses version 6.11.2

```
/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/bower -> /home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/gulp -> /home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
/home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/nodemon -> /home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js
```

I have tried downloading node v8.11.1 to the /home/jenkins/.nvm/versions/node/, copying gulp, nodemon and bower to the bin directories and using `nvm alias default v8.11.1` to switch my node versions

Though, when I run the project it always runs on the older version. What could I do to force it to run to the 8.11.1 version?

Comment: May it be that you just using Nvm Wrapper Plugin in your project?

Comment: Can you post the output of `nvm list` right after you use `nvm alias default v8.11.1`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to restart Jenkins for it to start using/recognize the newer version of node.

Comment: For me, even after a machine restart (and another Jenkins restart) it didn't work.